# Use a querystring parameter in a CAML Query

Tags: web-part, visual-studio, visual-web-part

I want to pass a parameter between two separate web parts I am developing. In my 'Detail' webpart i need to build a CAML query to display the correct profile based on their name.

```
pdquery.Query = "<Where>"+
                   "<Eq>"+
                       "<FieldRef Name='Name'/>"+
                       "<Value Type='Text'>{parameter}</Value>"+
                   "</Eq>"+
                "</Where>"
```

not sure how i get the parameter into the Query...is this even possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Erm - you can just concatenate it into the string?

```
pdquery.Query = "<Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Name'/><Value Type='Text'>"
                  + yourParameter + "</Value></Eq></Where>"
```

Comment: where yourParameter = Page.Request.QueryString["yourParameter"]

Comment: Yes ended up getting it about 5 minutes after I posted! Why it took me an hour to work that out I'll never know...